# configuration of twitter finagle redis client with tls enabled

Tags: scala, redis, twitter-finagle

How do I configure the finagle Redis client with tls-enabled?

```
    @Provides
def providesRedisClient(@Flag("redis-addr") host: String): redis.Client = {
    redis.Client(host)
}
```

as the function we used only took redis-endpiont.

Answer (score 0):

found following solution (just replace redis.Client(host) with the code below):

```
redis.Client(Redis.client.withTransport.tls(host).newClient(host))
```